# Leaflet markers showing up twice with laravel mix

Tags: leaflet, laravel-mix

My leaflet markers are showing up twice when I use leaflet through npm and laravel mix.

The second marker seems to be a slightly different fatter shape behind the first.

If I use a CDN then they work fine.

This is my code

```
$.getJSON('{{route('markers.json')}}', function(markers){
        var bounds = [];
        for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i ) {
           thisMarker = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng] ).addTo( mymap );
           bounds.push([markers[i].lat,markers[i].lng]);
        }
        console.log(bounds);
        mymap.fitBounds(bounds);            
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awh3d.png)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with Vue2Leaflet and Laravel Mix and I found a workaround here: https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet/issues/28

I'm not sure if you've managed to solve it so far or you've chosen another solution, but someone else might be interested in this too. So this is the code worked for me with Vue 2.x, `leaflet@1.7.1`, `vue2-leaflet@2.7.0` and `laravel-mix@6.0.19`:

```js
import * as L from 'leaflet'

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png').default,
  iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png').default,
  shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png').default,
})
```